# When opening an existing session and an existing file at the same time, the focus goes to the last opened file in the session

Tags: buffers, sessions

When doing this:

```
vim -S Session.vim OTHER_FILE
```

The shown buffer contains the last opened file in the `Session.vim` and not the file `OTHER_FILE`.  I find this behavior a bit disturbing, I would have found it more coherent to show the content of the file `OTHER_FILE`.  (`OTHER_FILE` does not appear in the `Session.vim` file)

After reading the Vim documentation, it appears that session files are loaded after having opened other files provided by arguments.  So if the session contains an `edit` statement, this is logical that the shown buffer contains the file of that `edit` statement.

With the help of the following function, it now shows the last file provided by argument:

```
function! GoToLastArgumentFile()                                                                  
    let l:current_buf_id = bufnr('%')                                           
    let l:highest_buf_id = l:current_buf_id                                     
                                                                                
    for buf_id in range(1, bufnr('$'))                                          
        if bufexists(buf_id) && l:current_buf_id != buf_id && bufloaded(buf_id) 
            let l:highest_buf_id = buf_id                                       
        endif                                                                   
    endfor                                                                      
                                                                                
    if l:highest_buf_id < l:current_buf_id                                      
        execute ":buffer ".l:highest_buf_id                                     
    endif                                                                       
endfunction
```

And also by adding this line in the .vimrc file:

```
autocmd! VimEnter * :call GoToLastArgumentFile()
```

I am pretty new at vim script, I found that solution a bit complicated and I was wondering if there was any better way to change the default behavior ?

Comment: A proponent of the KISS philosophy might consider just starting with `vim OTHER_FILE` and when ready to work on the session-based stuff do `:source Session.vim`.

Comment: Just FYI, there is a `SessionLoadPost` autocmd event. If it works as one would expect that's probably a more appropriate trigger than the general `VimEnter`.

Comment: @BLayer, in fact I was in the KISS philosophy for the last few years. I only started to have needs for kindof IDE features a few weeks ago. Only a reduced description of my issue is posted here, it is part of a more complicated configuration.
Thanks a lot for suggesting the event `SessionLoadPost`.  It is a way better idea than `VimEnter` in this case.  I am going to to do a few tests then I will update my question.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Indeed, you might want to explain the motivation for restoring a session *and* opening a file in the same command-line. Using a session is usually good for when you're saving and restoring your workspace. So why not restore it and *then* open the other file? If you're using a session for something different, that might explain it... In which case, you might want to explain what you're trying to accomplish, so you can get better advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat a little using this method:

```
vim -S Session.vim -c ":e OTHER_FILE"
```

This will source your Session.vim then load the file you want.
From what I have read in the man page, the commands specified with -c will be executed last:

```
+{command}
-c {command}
    {command} will be executed after the first file has been read. {command} is interpreted
    as an Ex command. If the {command} contains spaces it must be enclosed in double quotes 
    (this depends on the shell that is used). Example: Vim "+set si" main.c
    Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.
```

It won't change the initial behaviour of vim but it will always work.